# SSRS gauge component stop working with error in designer but work in preview

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

In ssrs 2012 everything was ok.

But one day, when I drag `Gauge` from toolbox the components, I get an error like

[image: Gauge Errore]

- SQL Server edition is 2012
- SQL Server data tool is 2010

I try to reinstall SQL Server Data Tools 2012 and again I get this error.

I try install SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2012 and again error.

The gauge that I created before give me this errore in designer but work in preview - what's the problem? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It looks like one of the Gauge properties is blank when it should have a valid Int32 value. Open the Properties window and check the values there. Worst case, open the report in Code view and see what is missing in the XML.

Comment: hi chris,i check the property and there is no missing value.even what you say is true,why pure gauge must has this error

Comment: I don't know, I'm just guessing which is why I put it as a comment rather than an answer. Did you open in Code view and check the XML?

Comment: thank for your comment.i copy whole gauge code from Code view and past to report in another machine it works fine in that machine.i think somthing like dll behind gauge is corrupt how can i replace this dll with good one?